# Scopes for migration from Google+ Sign-In to Google Sign-In

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I received a mail from Google informing me that I've got till March 7 to ensure my project is no longer using affected Google+ APIs that will be depreciated.
Here's my current implementation when constructing Google sign-in:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Now from what I read in the documentation: "By using GoogleSignInOptions.Builder with the DEFAULT_SIGN_IN option, you will automatically request the profile scope which provides the user’s name and profile picture"

The mail says the **plus.people.get** corresponds to the Google+ API method that is still used (and will be depreciated) and shutdown.

**If you see API calls to people.get, these can be the result of using the Google+ Sign-In feature in your application, which is now fully deprecated and is being shut down. Developers should migrate from the Google+ Sign-In feature to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in authentication system.**

I published an update of my app to the store 1 month ago. Do I need to make some changes in my app (for Google sign in) again before republishing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get same mail and I was confused. First of all. You could get this mail also by using some Google+ widgets (for example on your site - buttons etc).

I'm not sure if you get second mail [Correction] in the title.

> Earlier this week we sent you an email related to your projects that will be impacted by the Google+ API shutdown, which also affects
>   requests for Google+ OAuth scopes.
>
> The email listed that one or more of your projects are requesting the
>   “plus.me” scope, and would thus be affected. We would like to clarify
>   that only projects directly requesting the “plus.me” scope are
>   affected. This scope may have been listed in some emails, even if not
>   directly requested by your project. We apologize for any confusion
>   caused.
>
> If you are directly requesting the “plus.me” scope, any other Google+
>   OAuth scopes, or making any Google+ API calls, please ensure that you
>   remove these requests from your project before March 7, 2019.
>
> To see if your project is directly requesting the “plus.me” or any
>   other Google+ OAuth scopes:
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes
>
> If your project is written in Google Apps Script, you can view which
>   scopes your project is requesting by reviewing your project properties
>   in App Script Editor. If your project is not written in Google Apps
>   Script, please check your code for references to “plus.me” in OAuth
>   scope requests. We recommend that you review projects using any
>   3rd-party libraries that support sign-in or social functionality, as
>   these may also be affected by the shutdown. Thanks for being a valued
>   Google+ Developer.

Make sure to read this also. You'll find some instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/quick-migration-guide

And it looks like you are using new GoogleSignIn API so you should be OK. I'm using the same method right now. Make sure to use one of the latest version of Play Services in your gradle.

You can still getting some requests for old API when your users didn't update your apk or using your apk from a third-party Play Store (installed manually). We can't do nothing about it.

Comment: Hey @adek I didn't received the 2nd mail....we just received one this week

Comment: But I'm using the "plus.people.get" which is quite different and I'm on android.

Comment: @ClaudeHangui I'm also on Android. I asked Google about it and I get this info. But you should be OK. They've started killing this API starting January and in a few days we'll have final closure. 
I think that if you've been using Google widgets on your site (the one for +1) - this is it.

Comment: The project mentioned in the mail is the Android app project.

Comment: @ClaudeHangui that was my concern. I've got only app, I got these mails. I didn't use API for web. But just like you, I've migrated to new SignIn, I'm using it the same way, as I know - this is safe.

Comment: @ClaudeHangui. Look also in your code for depreciated methods info. If you don't see them - you are good.